# How to use Apify to log in to a site and click a button?

Tags: puppeteer, zapier, apify

I need use [Apify](http://www.apify.com) and [Zapier](http://www.zapier.com) to automate i) logging-in to a password-protected web page and ii) clicking a button. How can I do this?

I think I should be using Puppeteer in Actor, but I'm not certain how.

Target URLs will change from time to time. Their format is `https://studio.example.com/products/videocloud/media/videos/{id_code}` where `{id_code}` is, for example, `6091481925001`.

## 1. Zapier

Zapier should invoke an Apify Actor to do the work. An action in an existing zap already has access to the dynamic `{id_code}`. An additional action should "Run Actor" to Apify, passing either `{id_code}` or full URL `https://studio.example.com/products/videocloud/media/videos/6091481925001` to Apify to run on.

**How do I properly pass the value to Apify through "Input Body"?**

[image]

## 2. Login

When accessed whilst unauthenticated, the page redirects to a login form at `https://signin.example.com/?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fstudio.example.com%2Fproducts%2Fvideocloud%2Fmedia%2Fvideos%2F6091481925001` with:

- "Email Address" (`input` with `id="email"` and `name="email"`)
- "Password" (`input` with `id="password"` and `name="password"`)
- "Sign In" button (`button` with `id="signinButton"` and `type="submit"`)

**How do I use an Actor to log in here?**

[image]

## 3. Click

Once authenticated, the target page appears. It has a button bar including the button "Activate" (`button` whose child `span` text must only be "Activate" if we are allowed to click it).

(For info - once clicked, the button text should become "Deactivate").

**How do I get Apify to click the "Activate" button here?**

[image]

As I understand it, this is not a *scraping* job, since I am not looking to return data from the web page, so I should not be using [apify/puppeteer-scraper](https://apify.com/apify/puppeteer-scraper) or [apify/web-scraper](https://apify.com/docs/scraping/tutorial/web-scraper).

## Update:

So far, I have the following. However, Puppeteer inside Apify times out - at fairly lengthy values up to 9000ms, suggesting it isn't necessarily a page-load issue (?)

```
const Apify = require('apify');

    Apify.main(async () => {



        // Get credentials
        const { EMAIL, PASSWORD } = Apify.getEnv();         // Docs for using values: https://apify.com/docs/actor#source-env-vars


        // Launch Puppeteer
        const browser = await Apify.launchPuppeteer();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://signin.example.com/login');

        // Login
        await page.type('#email', process.env.EMAIL);
        console.log('Attempted to enter email');

        await page.type('#password', process.env.PASSWORD);
        console.log('Attempted to enter password');

        await page.click('#signinButton');
        console.log('Attempted to click button');    

        // Times-out here

        await page.waitForNavigation();
        console.log('Attempted to wait for navigation');

        // Get cookies
        const cookies = await page.cookies();
        console.log('Attempted to wait for cookies');

        await browser.close();

        console.log('Done.');


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can pass arbitrary JSON to the input. It makes sense to pass just the as

```
{
   "id_code": "ID_CODE_FROM_ZAPIER"
}
```

2) On Apify's side, you will need to read the input first with

```
const input = await Apify.getInput();
const { id_code } = input;
```

Then you need to get your credentials. If they don't change, I would save them as the environment variables of the actor. If you name them `EMAIL` and `PASSWORD`, you can then access them in the code via

```
const { EMAIL, PASSWORD } = Apify.getEnv();
```

Now you need to launch Puppeteer, go to the login page, fill the input fields and click submit. It is pretty easy, the examples are shown in this [article](https://help.apify.com/en/articles/1640711-how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-puppeteer). You don't need to worry about the cookies now.

3) Once you log in, you need to go to your desired URL via

```
await page.goto(`https://studio.example.com/products/videocloud/media/videos/${id_code}`)
```

To find the exact element to click when it doesn't have useful selectors is doable with JQuery and finding the text. I cannot log in so I'm not 100% sure this will work.

```
// We need to inject JQuery first
await Apify.utils.puppeteer.injectJQuery(page);

// We can use JQuery only in the browser context, which means inside evaluate
await page.evaluate(() => {
    $('button:contains("Activate")').click()
})
```

Comment: Lukas, thanks. for the starters. I have created the code I added to the question, to satisfy (2) - the initial login. However, the process times out at `await page.waitForNavigation();`, even at lengthy wait times. What is going wrong? NB1. The linked example shows credentials with `input` but, to get them from `getEnv()`, I followed docs and used `process.env.VARNAME`. NB2 tests for env vars `EMAIL` and `PASSWORD` return the set values okay.  NB3 Puppeteer throws no problem with any of the selector construction for the email, password or submit button.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could play with the **waitUntil** parameter e.g.

```js
await page.waitForNavigation({
   waitUntil: "networkidle2"  
});
```

** Check the docs for more info https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.20.0&show=api-pagewaitfornavigationoptions

2. Or you could wait for an element **selector** to appear in page 
   e.g.

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.buttonSelector')
```

** Check the docs for more info https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.20.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectorselector-options